# Testing if the binary representation of an integer has an odd number of ones

Tags: bitwise, rust

The `fn odd_ones(x: u32) -> bool` function should return `true` when `x` contains a odd number of 1s.

**Assumption:**

1. `x` is 32 bit unsigned.

**Restriction:**

1. The code should contain a total of at most 12 arithmetic, bitwise and logical operations.

**Forbidden:**

1. Conditionals, loops, function calls and macros.
2. Division, modulus and multiplication.
3. Relative comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`).

**Allowed operations:**

1. All bit level and logic operations.
2. Left and right shifts, but only with shift amounts between 0 and w - 1
3. Addition and subtraction.
4. Equality (`==`) and inequality (`!=`) tests.
5. Casting between `u32` and `i32`.

---

**My code:** ([Rust playground](http://is.gd/OaFj7o))

```
fn odd_ones(x: u32) -> bool {   
   let mid = (x >> 16) ^ x;
   let mid2 = (mid >> 8) ^ mid;
   let mid3 = (mid2 >> 4) ^ mid2;
   let mid4 = (mid3 >> 2) ^ mid3;

   (((mid4 >> 1) ^ mid4) & 1) == 1
}

fn odd_ones_test(x: u32) -> bool {    
    let sum = (0..32).map(|y| x >> y )
                     .fold(0, |sum ,y| sum + (y & 1));
    sum % 2 != 0
}

fn test (from: u32, to: u32) -> bool {
    (from..to).all(|x| odd_ones_test(x) == odd_ones(x))
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", test(!0 - 45345, !0));   
}
```

Any better way of doing this?

Comment: For the record, I believe this is called the binary parity of a number.

Comment: Weird world. Though both C and Rust claim they are system-programming languages, neither of them directly support common bit operations (that are on modern processors natively supported) like popcount or parity... In C's case there are compiler extensions, in `gcc` you would use `__builtin_parity`. Isn't something similar in Rust?

Comment: Several other possible solutions here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityNaive

Comment: Why exactly do you have all of these restrictions? It sounds like this is homework problem or a job interview question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath depends what you mean by "directly support". The [Rust implementation of `count_ones` uses LLVM intrinsics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L1185-L1194), which seems likely to call the x86_64 `popcnt` instruction *when available*. Remember that Rust is meant to be used on multiple processor architectures, and `popcnt` is SSE 4.2, so it's comparatively new. Of course, both C and Rust allow raw assembly, so you can always access it.

Comment: @Shepmaster It is, its taken from a homework exercise of the book Computer systems a programmer perspective 3rd edition. I' m reading it in my spare time.

Comment: And because I enjoy being pedantic ^_^, I'll point out that even things like `>>` and `&` are functions in Rust, implemented via the [`Shr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Shr.html) and [`BitOr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.BitOr.html) traits, respectivelt. Therefore your problem is **impossible** to complete in Rust.

Comment: @Shepmaster well that operations are explicitly mention as allowed.

Comment: @Shepmaster: assembly is really not an option if you want to be portable (as the chip might not support the instruction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leveraging code that other people wrote is always a great idea. In this case, there is [`count_ones`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.count_ones):

```
fn odd_ones(x: u32) -> bool {  
    x.count_ones() % 2 == 1
}
```

This method [is a shim](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L1185-L1194) for the LLVM intrinsic `@llvm.ctpop.i32`, which seems likely to become the very optimized SSE4.2 `popcnt` instruction when available.

Beyond that, you have some poor indentation habits. Rust uses 4-space indents, not the 3 (?!?) spaces you have in your `odd_ones` function.

There should not be a space between a function name and the arguments, whether in the function definition or the function call. Your `test` method should be fixed.

Be consistent with your spacing on commas. No space before, one space after. `|sum ,y|` is just wrong.

You should give names to magic constants. A rogue `32` laying around doesn't mean anything. Give it a name like `BITS_IN_U32`. There's an [unstable constant](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/u32/constant.BITS.html) that you might be able to use someday.

When mapping and folding over an iterator, you might as well put all the mapping into the `map` call. There's no reason to do the bitwise-and in the `fold`.

I have *no idea* what `!0 - 45345` is supposed to mean or why those particular values are useful. That's bad news when you try to understand this code in the future.

```
const BITS_IN_U32: usize = 32;

fn odd_ones(x: u32) -> bool {  
    x.count_ones() % 2 == 1
}

fn odd_ones_test(x: u32) -> bool {    
    let sum = 
        (0..BITS_IN_U32)
        .map(|y| (x >> y) & 1)
        .fold(0, |sum, y| sum + y);
    sum % 2 != 0
}

fn test(from: u32, to: u32) -> bool {
    (from..to).all(|x| odd_ones_test(x) == odd_ones(x))
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", test(!0 - 45345, !0));   
}
```

Comment: 1. Calling modulus operation or functions is forbidden.  2. !0 is to represent u32 max value and I wasn't sure what constant rust uses for that, but it was a random choice anyway. 2. "Face palm" cant believe I didn't saw  I could pass it everything to the map function :/, good catch .  3. I know it is usually good practice to named constants at the top but in this particular case I don't see it that beneficial . If I change the constant I would have to change the data type as well (That is just my opinion though).

Answer (score 1):

Once I had to count the bits that were set in an array of one million integers.  After several naive(very slow) starts I came across some bit twiddling hacks that sped things up dramatically. This is a C# function that contains two methods.

```
private bool isOddOnes(UInt32 numToCheck)
{
    //first  method
    //Dim bitsSetCt As UInt32 = 0
    //numToCheck = numToCheck - ((numToCheck >> 1) And &H55555555UI)
    //numToCheck = (numToCheck And &H33333333UI) + ((numToCheck >> 2) And &H33333333UI)
    //bitsSetCt = ((numToCheck + (numToCheck >> 4) And &HF0F0F0FUI) * &H1010101UI) >> 24

    //second method
    UInt32 bitsSetCt = default(UInt32);
    bitsSetCt = numToCheck - ((numToCheck >> 1) & 0x55555555u);
    bitsSetCt = ((bitsSetCt >> 2) & 0x33333333u) + (bitsSetCt & 0x33333333u);
    bitsSetCt = ((bitsSetCt >> 4) + bitsSetCt) & 0xf0f0f0fu;
    bitsSetCt = ((bitsSetCt >> 8) + bitsSetCt) & 0xff00ffu;
    bitsSetCt = ((bitsSetCt >> 16) + bitsSetCt) & 0xffffu;

    return (bitsSetCt & 1u) == 1u;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I already know a better way of doing this thanks to [this link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityNaive) given by [@glampert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39810/glampert) in the comments and none of the answers so far followed the rules, I will answer my own question to wrap things up:

```
fn odd_ones(x: u32) -> bool {
    let mut m = x ^ (x >> 16);
    m ^= m >> 8;
    m ^= m >> 4;
    m &= 0xf;
    ((0x6996 >> m) & 1) == 1
}
```

Using `0x6996` bit pattern saves up 2 operations. Also, the use of `^=` makes the code more compact.